# How to use pygments syntaxhighlier in mailchimp

Tags: jekyll, mailchimp, pygments

Mailchimp used my feed and send latest post in mail. I am using pygments highlighter with jekyll so it writes

```
{% highlight bash %}
some code here
{% endhighlight %}
```

in feed.xml and also while sending in email it does not convert this to highlighted code.
I want the code should be highlighted in email.

Comment: May i know instead of answering this question why it's down voted. If you not like this question then at least mention the reason in comment.

Answer (score 0):

So finally i find out the root cause of the issue. The actual issue with feed.xml

`jekyll-feed` do not style the code part.

After removing the `jekyll-feed` plugin and creating feed without plugin it's working fine as per my expectations.